# Lasso regression on boston crime dataset in python

Tags: python, lasso-regression

[Lasso regression solution in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOZ5z.png)

The above link contains the the code for solution of Lasso regression in R. I am trying to solve it in python. Can someone help me out to solve it python??

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EeTB.png)

Output of it is as in the above picture.

Comment: Can you include code of what you've tried in python, maybe we can give you more specific pointers that way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below approach

from imp import new_module from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV,
Lasso new_module = LassoCV(cv=5, random_state=0, max_iter=10000)
new_module.fit(train_x, train_y) new_module.alpha_

```
BestLassofit = Lasso(alpha=model.alpha_) BestLassofit.fit(train_x,
    train_y) importance = np.abs(BestLassofit.coef_)[1:] importance[:10]
    
Col = np.array(df.Col)[importance > 0] x =
    sm.add_constant(df[Col])
    
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y =
    sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(
        x, crimerate_df, test_size=0.2, random_state=123 )
train_x_tmp = sm.add_constant(train_x)
    
lmod = sm.OLS(train_y, train_x_tmp).fit() lmod.summary()
    
lmod.predict()[:10]
    
lmod.get_prediction().summary_frame()[:10]
    
sm.qqplot(lmod.resid,line="q") plt.title("Q-Q plot of Standardized
    Residuals")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of `scikit-learn`'s linear models module, where you can find [`sklearn.linear_model.Lasso`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) for an out-of-the-box Lasso regression implementation.

Example from the docs:

```py
>>> from sklearn import linear_model
>>> clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.1)
>>> clf.fit([[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])
Lasso(alpha=0.1)
>>> print(clf.coef_)
[0.85 0.  ]
>>> print(clf.intercept_)
0.15...
```

The link you sent seems to want you to tune the "shrinkage" parameter (which I imagine is `alpha`), so you could create a loop where you iterate over values of `alpha`, record the `score` (i.e. dataset error), and create the plot they display in the link.

Comment: I tried it but couldn't convert the above code to python. Moreover i am getting completely different graph when compared to that of output given.

Comment: @Michael the above code *is* python

Comment: You need to elaborate. The above code is in python already. The plot might not be exactly the same as the R plot, but you should see a similar ideal parameter.

Comment: Due to random seeds, you will *not* get the exact result compared to R.